# ExtJS 4 - How can I show toolbar item text only in overflow mode?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have toolbar with items , currently there are only icons in the items (text set to ""). but I want that in overflow mode (when toolbar exceeds screen width) I'll have text next to the item icon.

How can I do that ?!

The text in the overflow mode comes from the item's text (and if I set it , I'll have text in the regular toolbar)

Here is example of the 2 modes I'm talking about.

[image]

with overFlow ...

[image]

Comment: This requirement seems contradictory to me: When you have enough place to show the text, you don't want to show it; when there is not enough place, you want to show it ?

Comment: Added images to clarify my question ,My app has 12 icons in toolbar with tool tip. but when opening the app on smaller screens (like laptop) the overFlow gives drop down menu with small icons only and blank line next to them , that's where I want to show text.

Comment: With these images your question is clear now. Unfortunately I don't have the expertise to give an answer. Maybe someone else...

Comment: At least my question make sense :)

Comment: Hey. Did you find answer to that problem?